# How is ifplugd already running for wlan0

Tags: networking, pi-2

So I boot up Pi 2 to default run level 2 and the `ifplugd` daemon is started for `wlan0` when the networking script starts in `rcS.d`.

When the boot process continues and finally reaches the `ifplugd` script in `rc2.d` it skips over `wlan0` because it already has a running instance.

How does the `ifup` command in `rcS.d/networking` script cause `ifplugd` to fire when there is no direct reference to `ifplugd` in that script?

Comment: Although the duplicate does not actually have an answer, they are the same question being asked by the same person and the other question is better detailed.

Comment: I received a message in my inbox that my question was deleted hence the new question.